# send numbers in UDP socket in java

Tags: java

I am trying to send random numbers inside a UDP socket using this code below but the command `sendData = number.getBytes();` is not working. Is it because I have to replace `getBytes` with something else?

```
public class UDPServer {

    public void run() throws IOException {
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(5555);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = 
                new DatagramPacket(receiveData,                       
                        receiveData.length);

            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
            int port = receivePacket.getPort();
            Random dice = new Random();
            int number;

            for (int counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++) {
                number = dice.nextInt(6);
            }

            sendData = number.getBytes();

            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData,
                    sendData.length, IPAddress, port);

            serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem... when you say something else?

Comment: I don't think there is a getBytes() method for `int`s is there?

Comment: An `int` is a primitive type and a primitive type has no methods; what is more, `Integer` (which is the wrapper class) has no `.getBytes()`. Hint: use a `ByteBuffer`.

Comment: chanumber is not STring type..u caanot call getByte[]

Answer (score 1):

I take it you want to write the bytes of your `int`s in network byte order. Good. Java has a class for it: `ByteBuffer`.

Sample code, modify for your needs:

```
final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(8); // for 2 ints, an int is 4 bytes long
buf.putInt(4);
buf.putInt(3);
buf.rewind();
final DatagramPacket packet
    = new DatagramPacket(buf.array(), buf.limit(), addr, port);
```

`ByteBuffer` does big endian by default, which is the network byte order. See its `.order()` method.